Create a zip code form
Is it possible to create code for a WordPress page (or create a plugin) that will allow a visitor to enter their post code (zip code) and see a price as a result.
Something like a form field box where if X=A,B,C,D,E, then display £100.  If X=F,G,H,J,K, then display £125.
I'm a photographer by trade and I have a minimum pricing requirements. The further outside the city, the higher the price.
I have an image showing these price minimums but visitors don't click on it often.
I have basic knowledge of JavaScript and PHP.
Thanks in advance for anyone's thoughts and replies.
Frank

WordPress (or any other CMS) doesn't have this feature by default. You need to find a plugin (I doubt if the exact plugin like this exist), or build your own code.
I suppose your code should have a form for user to enter their post code. Based on the post code value, you can determine the price in one of the following ways:

Give the prices if the post code contains or starts with certain letter.
Use Google Maps API to measure the distance between your location and the entered post code location. If the distance is in a given range, give it a certain price.


The Google Maps API seems like the solution Anh. Thanks for bringing it to light for me. All the best!
